# how can I put an image on another block in css ( i mean the locating)

Tags: css, image

how can I give a location to my image that I want to be on another banner block?

```
#topBar{
            background-color: #333333;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px ;

        }
#logo{
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            position: fixed;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
```

and I want the logo to be on the topBar

Comment: Please add your HTML structure to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get you correctly. this will do what you wants.

```css
#topBar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar"></div>
<div id="logo"></div>
```

PS: Your question is vague. Please read  [tips on writing great answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)